# Restricting dates in gravity forms calendar

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, gravityforms, datefield

Query regarding adding logic to date (calender) field in gravity forms.

I want to disable past days, weekends and only enable today’s date +3 days (excluding weekends). This is what I have come up with-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
        if ( formId == 16 && fieldId == 1 ) {
            optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
            optionsObj.beforeShowDay = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends;
    optionsObj.minDate = 0;
            optionsObj.maxDate = '+3 D';
        }
        return optionsObj;
    });
    </script>
```

The only issue as you can see in the screenshot also- the next 3 weekdays days are not active. It is counting weekends too. Ideally, the active dates should be 22nd, 23rd, 24th and 27th. How do I make changes here? any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 12 && fieldId == 56) {
        optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends;
        optionsObj.minDate = 0;
        const d = new Date();
        let day = d.getDay()
        if(day < 3 ){
            optionsObj.maxDate = '+3 D';
        }else if (day == 6){
           optionsObj.maxDate = '+4 D'; 
        }else if (day > 2 && day < 6){
            optionsObj.maxDate = '+5 D';
        }
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
</script>
```